# PHP mailer unsubscribe inline without opening url in browser

Tags: php, outlook, phpmailer, inline-editing

i was wondering if possible to use PHP mailer to send emails to unsubscribe inline without opening url in browser and the end users are using outlook. if this possible then also adding comment inline in the email and having a submit button for feedback information?

Answer (score 1):

HTML messages are displayed by Word in Outlook, not IE.

It does not run any scripts or forms in the message HTML by design. A link is the best you get.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible. If you want a feedback form, it needs to be on a web page.

Comment: ow come on, nothing is impossible if you have looked at Microsoft workflow they have something similar, in the outlook you can even add new comments.